# Is there a way to see units' health-bars?

Tags: tower-wars

Seeing health-bars would be incredibly useful for determining, for instance, how powerful each tower actually is.  Is there a way to show health-bars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that you can do this by hitting <kbd>f2</kbd>   *(there is no way of doing it from the UI)*.

As a side-note, you can see how powerful each of the towers/units are on the [towerwars wiki](http://wiki.towerwarsgame.com/index.php?title=Towers).